# Select highest total amount in different tables (Access)

Tags: ms-access, sum, max

I have 2 tables: "**sales**" and "**services**". Both tables have these fields: *customer* and *amount*

I need to retrieve the customer with the highest total amount (sum all amounts), between dates., in the both tables.

Example:

> **sales**
>
> Mary | $100
>
> John | $200
>
> Mary | $200
>
> **services**
>
> Mary | $40
>
> John | $300

If we sum all amounts of every customer we obtain:

> Mary | $340
>
> John | $500

Then the customer with the highest total amount is: John

But how I can do this using an Access' query ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Sounds like you have a schema error, as to me, services are a type of sales, so both should be in the same table. Any time you have two tables with the same columns it should be a red flag that you probably have a single entity stored in two different tables.

Comment: This is only a basic example to explain better my doubt. But the real case is some different. Both tables have 30 different fields except total and customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a union query would be most appropriate:

```
SELECT Top 1 Customer, Sum(Amount) As Total FROM
(SELECT Customer, Amount, Date FROM Sales
UNION ALL
SELECT Customer, Amount, Date FROM Services)
WHERE Date Between Date() AND Date()-30
GROUP BY Customer
ORDER BY Sum(Amount) DESC
```

Comment: First, I have tried this query and runs fine!! :-)

thank you very much for both replies (Remou and Rossfabricant)

Regards